# My JSON string not recive complete via HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, php, json

when i send my array to my php file it incomplete recive to php file.
my arr varible is :

```
[["╪▒┘à┘╛┘╪د","67126881188552864","Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,8644,-360,-4,8691,-3
.48,-313,1015,4.334 M,1392/12/28,12:30:08,3.99 M,10 B,10%,530,16.4,16.38,┘à╪ش╪د╪
▓,7,3130,8644,1,50,5000,&nbsp;,&nbsp;,&nbsp;,8644,11553,359,307,8645,1,1,8655,11
030,2,┌»╪▒┘ê┘ç ┘à┘╛┘╪د (╪│┘ç╪د┘à┘è ╪╣╪د┘à) (╪▒┘à┘╛┘╪د),╪ذ╪د╪▓╪د╪▒ ╪د┘ê┘ (╪ز╪د
╪ذ┘┘ê┘è ╪د╪╡┘┘è) ╪ذ┘ê╪▒╪│ ,connOK"]]
```

i send data with HTTP GET request like below

```
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);

    page.open('http://localhost/bptest/danger/get.php?data='+myJsonString,function(status){
            console.log("Page opened");
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL');
            } else {
                console.log("REPLY FROM SERVER:");
                console.log(page.content);
            }});
```

end my simple php file is below code :

```
<li><?php echo $_GET["data"]; ?></li>
```

and php get's this :

```
[["?????","67126881188552864","Empty,Empty,Empty,Em
pty,8644,-360,-4,8691,-3.48,-313,1015,4.334 M,1392/12/28,12:30:08,3.99 M,10 B,10
%,530,16.4,16.38,????,7,3130,8644,1,50,5000,
```

why it's crash when recive from php and how i can fix this

Comment: you've got a charset mismatch, and are dumping (say) utf8 text into a (say) iso8859 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` line (and the file itself should be in UTF-8 which should be the default for any decent text editor) and also the use of [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which is when you want to encode something to fit into the query string (since unlike `encodeURI`, it also encodes characters like `&` and `=`).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
var arr = [["╪▒┘à┘╛┘╪د","67126881188552864","Empty,Empty,Empty,Empty,8644,-360,-4,8691,-3\
.48,-313,1015,4.334 M,1392/12/28,12:30:08,3.99 M,10 B,10%,530,16.4,16.38,┘à╪ش╪د╪\
▓,7,3130,8644,1,50,5000,&nbsp;,&nbsp;,&nbsp;,8644,11553,359,307,8645,1,1,8655,11\
030,2,┌»╪▒┘ê┘ç ┘à┘╛┘╪د (╪│┘ç╪د┘à┘è ╪╣╪د┘à) (╪▒┘à┘╛┘╪د),╪ذ╪د╪▓╪د╪▒ ╪د┘ê┘ (╪ز╪د\
╪ذ┘┘ê┘è ╪د╪╡┘┘è) ╪ذ┘ê╪▒╪│ ,connOK"]];
var myJsonString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr));

page.open('http://localhost/bptest/danger/get.php?data='+myJsonString,function(status){
    console.log("Page opened");
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('FAIL');
    } else {
        console.log("REPLY FROM SERVER:");
        console.log(page.content);
    }
});
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

**PHP:**

Note the security risk comment (you could also avoid the risk by using "text/plain" as the content-type but then it won't get rendered as HTML if you need that).

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['data']; // You better fix this after testing, as it invites XSS scripting attacks!
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use encodeURI() to encode you json string.

Please see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI.

Answer (score 1):

You must use UTF-8 charset  with JSON. Check this points:

- Header charset
- Encoding php file with UTF-8
- Check if receveid data are UTF-8 encoded

I think the charset is not good on one side of your app or is changed during the data transfer.

Comment: The receiving PHP file doesn't really need to be encoded with UTF-8 unless it has its own non-ASCII characters, though it is a good practice anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(encodeURI(arr));

    page.open('http://localhost/bptest/danger/get.php?data='+myJsonString,function(status){
            console.log("Page opened");
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL');
            } else {
                console.log("REPLY FROM SERVER:");
                console.log(page.content);
            }});
```